# Delphi anonymous function passed to inlined function

Tags: delphi, inline, anonymous-function, delphi-2009

I have stumbled upon an unexpected Delphi 2009 behaviour. After investigating a strange bug in my code, I managed to narrow down the issue and create a minimal example which I present below.

Of course, the following code prints the value 1:

```
program Example1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TIntFcn = reference to function(const X: integer): integer;

function fcn(AFunction: TIntFcn; a: integer): integer; inline;
begin
  result := AFunction(a);
end;

begin

  writeln(fcn(function(const X: integer): integer
    begin
      result := 1;
    end, 0));

end.
```

Similarly, this program prints the value 2:

```
program Example2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TIntFcn = reference to function(const X: integer): integer;

function fcn(AFunction: TIntFcn; a: integer): integer; inline;
begin
  result := AFunction(a);
end;

begin

  writeln(fcn(function(const X: integer): integer
    begin
      result := 2;
    end, 0));

end.
```

"Obviously", this third program prints the same value as the first one, namely, 1:

```
program Produce;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TIntFcn = reference to function(const X: integer): integer;

function fcn(AFunction: TIntFcn; a: integer): integer; inline;
begin
  result := AFunction(a);
end;

begin

  writeln(fcn(function(const X: integer): integer
    begin
      result := 1;
    end, 0));

  fcn(function(const X: integer): integer
    begin
      result := 2;
    end, 0); // discard the output

end.
```

However, the output isn't 1, but 2. It seems like the compiler uses the second anonymous function in the call to `fcn` in `writeln`.

To me this seems like a bug in the Delphi 2009 compiler, but it could also simply be my not understanding the more subtle details about anonymous functions in Delphi. What do you think?

Comment: FWIW, in 10.2 Tokyo, a `1` is displayed. In XE too. So this is probably a bug in how anonymous functions are handled in Delphi 2009.

Comment: I assume the second anonymous function somehow replaces the first one. I don't know how, though. But to me, it looks like a bug in Delphi 2009 too.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, Was just going to search in Quality Central, and found out it is gone!?. What is happening? And I agree that the anonumous frame is wrongly reused here, causing the first one to be replaced.

Comment: @LURD Did you mean that QC is gone? That surprises me too, although not too much. It has been deprecated for a while already and QP (Quality Portal) replaced it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, even if it is deprecated and won't accept new entries, it should be online for search. I consider that invaluable.

Comment: AFAIK, the entries were transferred. But any links will be gone.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, yes a couple of thousand links are likely ruined. As long as there is a new location, I would be pleased.

Comment: Quality Central appears to be down right now. And no QC tickets have been transferred to Quality Portal. Owners of existing QC tickets that are still open need to file new QP tickets manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, if we have that list...

Comment: Looks like QC might finally be dead.  qc.embarcadero.com now redirects to quality.embarcadero.com

Comment: That's one way of leaving the bugs behind. Very convenient ...

Comment: AFAIK all the issues ever reported to QC are tracked in the internal JIRA system. I am asking if there is any alternative url available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly appears to be a bug, and according to the comments received on the question, this has been fixed in Delphi XE. Probably the simplest workaround is to skip asking for inlining if the compiler cannot handle it correctly:

```
program Solve;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TIntFcn = reference to function(const X: integer): integer;

function fcn(AFunction: TIntFcn; a: integer): integer;
  {$IF CompilerVersion >= 22}inline;{$IFEND} {Warning: Horrible bug in Delphi 2009}
begin
  result := AFunction(a);
end;

begin

  writeln(fcn(function(const X: integer): integer
    begin
      result := 1;
    end, 0));

  fcn(function(const X: integer): integer
    begin
      result := 2;
    end, 0); // discard the output

end.
```

In most cases, the loss of performance should be negligible in Delphi 2009, and you do request inlining in XE and later. Of course, if you don't think inlining is important at all, you can simply remove the request altogether.